# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in ngIf?

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

**SharedServiceA:**

```
export class SharedServiceA {
    somethingWasUpdated = new Subject();

    updateSomething(value) {
        this.somethingWasUpdated.next(value);
    }
}
```

**AnotherService:**

```
export class AnotherService {
    doSomething() {
        this.sharedServiceA.updateSomething(true);
    }
}
```

**component-a.component.ts**

```
export class ComponentA {
    list = [];
    isShowList = false;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sharedServiceA.somethingWasUpdated
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data) {
                        this.fetchData(); // Get data from another service, then populate list
                    }
                }
            );
    }
    
    fetchData() {
        // Get data from another service
        if (dataFound) {
            this.list = dataFound;
            this.isShowList = true;
        } else {
            this.isShowList = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**component-a.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!isShowList"> <!-- This is where ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError points to: Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false' -->
    List empty
</div>
<div *ngIf="isShowList">
    Print something here
</div>
```

**component-b.component.html**

```
export class ComponentB {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.sharedServiceA.somethingWasUpdated
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed))
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data) {
                        // Get data from another service
                    }
                }
            );

        this.anotherService.doSomething(); // If I place this inside a setTimeout, I don't get the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    }
}
```

This is the scenario:

1. Click on a button > `ComponentA` gets created inside a tab
2. Click on another button > `ComponentB` gets created inside another tab (basically side by side with `ComponentA`) > `ComponentA.fetchData()` >  `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Why would I get an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in `ComponentA` after `list` was populated and `isShowList` was set to `true` and why don't I get the error if I place `this.anotherService.doSomething();` inside a `setTimeout`?

How is this code violating the unidirectional data flow? Even after reading several articles, I'm still confused in this particular case.

Comment: Create a stackblitz and you won't have to explain a lot may be.

Comment: You could try to put  this.anotherService.doSomething(); in a ‘later’ lifecyclehook..

Answer (score 0):

Quick point, ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked errors only visible in dev mode. Do not show in production mode.

Answer (score -1):

In your component use changeDectectorRef like below:

```
    import { ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}

  fetchData() {
        // Get data from another service
        if (dataFound) {
            this.list = dataFound;
            this.isShowList = true;
        } else {
            this.isShowList = false;
        }
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }
```

**2nd method**

If above doesnt work for you
  then use it in `AfterViewChecked` life cycle hooks.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
     this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Hope this helps you!!